# How can I put Component into Module in Joomla! site?

Tags: joomla, module, components, joomla-extensions

I wonder if exists a way to put component into module without install plugin, neither component nor module.

Thanks and my apologize for my bad English.

Comment: "*...into module **without** install plugin, **neither** component **nor** module*" No there isn't. You could try this [extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/components-anywhere) though.

Comment: That is a solution, but there is not it was looking for. Btw, thanks!

Comment: you could try a custom html module and put an iframe there with your component if it suits you.

Comment: I was thinking it, actually in "Joomla!" there is an option to set embed code in options module. The trouble of this, embed full page in it and not content from component so, how can i do this last one?

Comment: Use jquery to load only the `div` that contains the component. [See this](https://api.jquery.com/load/); the section *Loading Page Fragments*.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for your help. I'm gonna publish the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, should unable Editor from configuration site, in Panel Admin. Then, go to Extension -> Plugins -> TinyMCE and delete forbidden items "script".
Now, go to "create module", with custom HTML5 and put something like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="new-projects">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "urlOfYourComponent #idYouWouldShow" );
</script>
```

Thanks to Ilias cause the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this without installing any extensions is via a custom HTML joomla module where you'll place your component in an iframe. 
Then if you want to load only the component part of the fetched page in the iframe use jquery's [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm correct, You don't wanna install any kind of extension that do that, you ask for vanilla possibility to put component into module, so this is the answer, there is no way to put whole component into module. Partial Example: You can put article into custom HTML module or list categories into modules, but you will never see whole component into module. Why? Because component its a core thing on site, like people in building (or even the whole building) eg. house, and module is like painting on the wall, You can't put building on the painting.

Comment: I guess creating custom module referencing to my custom component, could do it but... i don't know if it's correct way to do for reason you gave.